# How does Airflow determine if task fails or succeeds, and schedule retries?

Tags: airflow

I'm very new to Airflow (just started reading up on it), and I have a couple of questions about how to determine if a task has failed or succeeded, and scheduling retries.

For example, the task I want to run is an API call that always returns a JSON object. Within the JSON object is a `msg` that tells me if the call has succeeded or failed. So in this case, to Airflow, will this task always be seen as success since a JSON object is always returned? If so, how do I indicate to Airflow the true status of this task after checking the `msg`?

And say I schedule the task to run weekly. But if the task fails, then I would set it to retry 3 more times every 10 min. If *that* fails, then I want it to retry one more time the next day. I know I can configure the 3 retries in the DAG, but is there a way to configure the retry on the next day too?

Answer (score 3):

We can separate all jobs executing on Airflow into two types of tasks:

- Sensors: Will run a small piece of code and depending on whether it returns True or False, it will either do another `poke` or reschedule the task to do another `poke` until it is out of time. Only when an exception occurs it will use the same `retry` logic as on the Operator side.
- Operators: This is the logic when the task at hand is not a sensor. This will run your piece of code (your BaseOperator) and if there is no exception raised, it is marked as success. Regarding the retry logic: If you specify `retries=3` as keyword-argument to your BaseOperator, it will retry 3 times. At the third retry it will either mark the task as `success` if no exception was present or `failed` if there was an exception. When a task should be retried, it's marked in state `up_for_retry`.